# Sql insertion via insensitive unique key

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have a column on my table which has unique key property, but i also want it to be unique in an insensitive manner.What happens is if there is a key like xyz, insert statement with values 
Xyz,xYZ works properly, which I want to prevent. What can i use to achieve this? 
(I am using postgresql.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this:

```
create unique index on tableName (lower(columnName))
```